# HTML forms submits automatically when used javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I was creating a website with `PHP`, I need to access my webcamera so I used javascript for it but, It causes some error that it automatically submits the form.

```
<tr>
   <td height="35">NEW IMAGE:</td>
   <td height="35">
      <div id="showImage" class="d-none">
   </td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td height="35">CAPTURE IMAGE</td>
   <td><button class="btn btn-warning text-white" id="accesscamera" data-target="#photoModal">
      Capture Photo
      </button>
   </td>
</tr>



<!-- outside </div> tag --!>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-894YE6QWD5I59HgZOGReFYm4dnWc1Qt5NtvYSaNcOP+u1T9qYdvdihz0PPSiiqn/+/3e7Jo4EaG7TubfWGUrMQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-+YQ4JLhjyBLPDQt//I+STsc9iw4uQqACwlvpslubQzn4u2UU2UFM80nGisd026JF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script src="./plugin/sweetalert/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./plugin/webcamjs/webcam.min.js"></script>
    <script src="edit_main.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">
</body>
```

my `main.js` file is here

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    Webcam.set({
        width: 240,
        height: 160,
        image_format: 'jpeg',
        jpeg_quality: 90
    });

   
    $('#accesscamera').on('click', function() {
        Webcam.reset();
        Webcam.on('error', function() {
            $('#photoModal').modal('hide');
            swal({
                title: 'Warning',
                text: 'Please give permission to access your webcam',
                icon: 'warning'
            });
        });
        Webcam.attach('#my_camera');
    });


    $('#takephoto').on('click', take_snapshot);

    $('#retakephoto').on('click', function() {
        $('#my_camera').addClass('d-block');
        $('#my_camera').removeClass('d-none');

        $('#results').addClass('d-none');

        $('#takephoto').addClass('d-block');
        $('#takephoto').removeClass('d-none');

        $('#retakephoto').addClass('d-none');
        $('#retakephoto').removeClass('d-block');

        $('#uploadphoto').addClass('d-none');
        $('#uploadphoto').removeClass('d-block');
    });

    
})

function take_snapshot()
{
    //take snapshot and get image data
    Webcam.snap(function(data_uri) {
        //display result image
        // $('#results').html('<img  src="' + data_uri + '" class="d-block mx-auto rounded"/>');

        $('#showImage').html('<img width="320" height="240" src="' + data_uri + '" class="d-block mx-auto rounded"/>');

        var raw_image_data = data_uri.replace(/^data\:image\/\w+\;base64\,/, '');
        $('#photoStore').val(raw_image_data);
    });
    Webcam.reset();

    $('#my_camera').removeClass('d-block');
    $('#my_camera').addClass('d-none');

    $('#results').removeClass('d-none');
    $('#showImage').removeClass('d-none');

    $('#takephoto').removeClass('d-block');
    $('#takephoto').addClass('d-none');

    $('#retakephoto').removeClass('d-none');
    $('#retakephoto').addClass('d-block');

    $('#uploadphoto').removeClass('d-none');
    $('#uploadphoto').addClass('d-block');

    $('#photoModal').modal('hide');
}
```

So, what actually it does is that it makes a popup and will attach the camera and I can view with the camera and I can capture the image. But whenever I click Capture image button the popup arises but now the form is automatically submitted.

The error caught on the console is

```
`i {name: 'WebcamError', stack: 'WebcamError: Could not locate DOM element to attac…com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js:2:41048)', message: 'Could not locate DOM element to attach to.'}
message: "Could not locate DOM element to attach to."
name: "WebcamError"
stack: "WebcamError: Could not locate DOM element to attach to.\n    at new i (http://localhost/ttgym/Files/dashboard/admin/plugin/webcamjs/webcam.min.js:2:164)\n    at Object.attach (http://localhost/ttgym/Files/dashboard/admin/plugin/webcamjs/webcam.min.js:2:3706)\n    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (http://localhost/ttgym/Files/dashboard/admin/main.js:22:16)\n    at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js:2:43064)\n    at HTMLButtonElement.v.handle (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js:2:41048)"
[[Prototype]]: Error` This is the error caught on console
```

Please help me with this!

Comment: Not seeing a form in your HTML or javascript.

Comment: This question doesn't seem to be related to PHP or CSS in any way. Please only add tags that are directly relevant to the issue at hand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
$('#accesscamera').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
 ...
}
```

Comment: So, When I do that thing it invokes on error function

Comment: @swamper if you have any other errors, you should do a codepen, including all js libraries from CDN, so we can help you.

Comment: Sorry to bother but updated the question with console error

Comment: Michela thanks for the help that solved it!! Thanks to the core

Comment: @swamper, for console error, seems to be missing <div id="my_camera"></div> in your html.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your form button type is `type="button"` and all click events should have preventDefault like this:

```
$('#selectore').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
 ...
}
```

Comment: So, it cause to invoke on error function

Answer (score 0):

Make your capture button to type **button** by default it is submit..

Comment: it's already in the button tag

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Yeah i know it is in button tag but by default button tag has type submit, so you've to make it <button type="button"></button>